# Toolbar in Tkinter (python3)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Is there a way to make a toolbar in pack(), and buttons below toolbar with grid()?
[I want to have result like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPutE.png)

My code:

```
class App:
    def __init__(self,root):


    self.toolbar = Frame(root,bg="gray",height=40)
    self.toolbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

    self.insertBtn = Button(self.toolbar, text="BUTTON")
    self.insertBtn.pack(side=LEFT)


    self.frame = Frame(root,bg="cyan")
    self.frame.pack()

    self.btn = Button(self.frame, text="1", width=4, height=2, bg="white")
    self.btn.grid(row=0,pady=4,padx=4)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')
app = App(root)

root.mainloop()
```

If there is no way to do that, how could I just put this button to the left edge of my window app like in the picture above?

Comment: It looks like you're already doing it. The toolbar is across the top, and there's one button in the toolbar. Is the only problem that the bottom frame doesn't fill the window?

Comment: I'd like to have this button not in the middle of my window but on the left side (like grid(row=0, column=0))

Comment: You're putting the bottom button in a frame, but you haven't configured the frame to fill the window. Have you tried using the options to `pack` so that the frame fills the bottom window?

Comment: Ok, I've added to self.frame.pack(side=LEFT) and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

**March 2020 Update**

For those searching for a predefined component I found a [tutorial here](http://zetcode.com/tkinter/menustoolbars/). I am not the author of this but I have tested it and it works

```
def initUI(self):

    menubar = Menu(self.master)
    self.master.config(menu=menubar)

    fileMenu = Menu(menubar)

    submenu = Menu(fileMenu)
    submenu.add_command(label="New feed")
    submenu.add_command(label="Bookmarks")
    submenu.add_command(label="Mail")
    fileMenu.add_cascade(label='Import', menu=submenu, underline=0)

    fileMenu.add_separator()

    fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", underline=0, command=self.onExit)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="File", underline=0, menu=fileMenu)
```

Comment: That's called a menu not a toolbar